# Android Programming on phone but Tablet

Tags: java, android, settings, setting

I am not an android developer but I am performing Alpha testing for one of the android application.
The app has two languages English and Odia.
The app when installed on Phone, it opens in both the languages but when the same is installed on tablet, it is showing garbage when Odia language is selected.
Can someone help me understand if this is something to be set in the app or or the tablet?
thanks in advance.

Comment: Check if Odia language is available on Device.

Comment: that solved the issue Gokul, it is the device which is not having Odia option in it.. kindly excuse delayed reponse but my remoteness to internet has chained me out of stackoverflow. :)